# Test for Many Worlds Hypothesis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, multiverse, schroedingers-cat

If one actually ran an experiment similar to the Schrodinger's cat thought experiment, and ran it enough times (with the same cat) to get the confidence interval good enough, could one say that suggests the many worlds hypothesis is true?

For example, with 50% probability of living, after 5 tests, there would only be a ~3% chance of the cat still being alive. If it is alive, then can we say with 95% confidence that it is true?

If it is true, then is my intuition correct that this experiment would fail in most worlds, but succeed in a few/one?

Comment: Can you spell out your suggestion in more detail?  If the cat is alive after 5 tests than we'd be in the 1/32th word where that happen or if the cat dies we'd be in the 31/32 words where that doesn't happen.  I don't see how the test actually determines whether or not many-words hypothesis is true.  Are you suggesting that if we get something very unlikely to happen (like the cat living 20 times in a row on a 50/50 test) then that would imply we're in the rare one in a million universe where that happens?

Comment: Also, Schroedinger's cat doesn't die with 50% probability.  Instead, the cat is in a superposition of both alive and dead at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, that was the thought. If it's still alive after 5 tries, then we're in the 1/32 world where it survived all 5 times.

I know it's not exactly the same as Schrodinger's cat. It's more a game of quantum Russian roulette, I guess. The point is that the probability based on a wave function. So, to remove the ambiguity, we just set up the experiment so that there is a 50% chance of an atom decaying and triggering the cat to be killed. Then run that experiment X times.

Comment: How could you tell the difference between something unlikely happening in our world versus being in the unlikely world where it was guaranteed?

Comment: How can you tell the difference with any experiment? With any drug trial, we treat a bunch of patients and say with X confidence that the drugs works because Y patients were cured. Could it have been a fluke and they all just randomly got better? Yes, but that's unlikely. It would suggest, not prove. Metaphysically speaking, nothing in physics or science in general is ever proven, just well supported.

Comment: The probability that a carbon 14 nucleus will survive 5700 years is 50%, so if you take 14g of carbon 14 and wait about half a million years you'll be left with one atom of carbon 14. The probability of that atom surving half a million years is $2^{-79}$, which is even less likely than me winning the National Lottery. Would you regard the survival of that atom as proof that many worlds exist?

Comment: I would think it would suggests that many worlds exist. Am I wrong? Judging from the specificity of your comment, I'm guessing that your example may be a counterexample to the validity of my test that I'm not getting.

Comment: @Tyler: I would say my example proves only that a chance of $1$ in $6.023 \times 10^{23}$ isn't that small when you start with $6.023 \times 10^{23}$ (i.e. 14g) carbon 14 atoms. In other words, observation of a vanishingly small probability proves nothing.

Comment: @Tyler Yes, I'm sorry to say but that's wrong. The outcome of *any* experiment in our world can tell you nothing about 'other possible universes', by definition.

Comment: @Tyler:  People do win lotteries.  Is that evidence for many worlds?

Comment: @Tyler: for the record you've asked a perfectly good question, and one that I've seen suggested elsewhere. Reading back my comment it probably sounds a bit sniffy, but it isn't meant to be. I don't know who downvoted your question and voted to close it, but I disagree with them.

Comment: I am also not sure who voted to close it (many worlds theory is a perfectly valid physics question), but I'm voting to keep it open (and am hoping that some of the comments here turn into answers).

Comment: Some argue that the outcome of the experiment tied to Bell's Theorem makes Many Worlds a far simpler model than Collapse plus the No-Communication Theorem. I don't see any flaw in the argument.